# How to install MongoDB on Ubuntu Mate 20.04 running on pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, mongodb

I have an instance of Ubuntu Mate 20.04 running on my Raspberry Pi 3 and I am wondering if it is possible to install MongoDB 4.2 without compiling it.

I am not sure where I can get the builds from.

How can I do that?

---

I tried to use the Package Manager:

```
$ sudo apt install mongodb-org
...
Unable to locate package mongodb-org
```

Comment: you running 64bit ubuntu? if not, then you can't even compile mongo 4.2

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't think so... `uname -a` shows `Linux rpi3 5.4.0-1012-raspi #12-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 27 04:13:46 UTC 2020 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: then there's no way of running mongodb version >= 3.2 - you need a 64bit operating system

Comment: @JaromandaX How can I install 3.2 then? Are there any builds for my configuration already?

Comment: what's available using the ubuntu package manager? (by the way, you can run 64bit ubuntu mate on a pi 3, though according to official documentation from ubuntu-mate, it only "kind of works" - not sure what that means - it "works" on pi4 and pi3+ though)

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried to follow the documentation and when I do `apt install mongodb-org` it says it `cannot locate package` but the packages show when I press tab to autocomplete. I would not change the OS because I have other stuff running on the same pi.

Comment: by the way - *How can I install 3.2 then* - I just said you can't ... 3.2 = 3.2 ... You can't install >= 3.2 in 32bit OS

Comment: @JaromandaX Well, I just want to install (preferably using a build) the latest MongoDB version that is compatible with my configuration...

Comment: `apt install mongodb-org` - have you added the mongodb.org repository?

Comment: actually, don't bother with mongodb-org - they DONT have images for ARM at all

Comment: seems the only thing you can do is install whatever mongodb (not mongodb-org) you can, or compile mongodb 3.1 from source

Comment: If you can get a 64-bit OS on your Pi, I have filled this repo with modern releases compiled for the Pi: https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries